# How to covert the first letter of a string to a uppercase

Tags: c

This is for a school assignment. The goal of this function is to randomly select a word from each array and create a new array with the first letter of each sentence capitalized, spaces between each word, and a period in the end 20 times. The sentence follows the format article, noun, verb, preposition, article, and noun.

My question is how do I go about capitalizing the first letter of each sentence? I tried to set the first position in the string to equal the char at that position - 32, but that just crashes the program.

```
void randomize(void) {

    char *article[] = {"the", "a", "one", "some", "any"};
    char *noun[] = {"boy", "girl", "dog", "town", "car"};
    char *verb[] = {"drove", "jumped", "ran", "walked", "skipped"};
    char *preposition[] = {"to", "from", "over", "under", "on"};
    char *sentence[6];

    int running = 1;

    while(running){

        int location = rand()%5;

        char *captFirstLetter = article[location];

        captFirstLetter[0] = captFirstLetter[0] - 32 ;

        sentence[0] = captFirstLetter;

        sentence[1] = noun[rand()%5];

        sentence[2] = verb[rand()%5];

        sentence[3] = preposition[rand()%5];

        sentence[4] = article[rand()%5];

        sentence[5] = noun[rand()%5];

        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            printf("%s%s%s", (i == 6) ? "" : sentence[i], (i > 4) ? "" : " ", (i == 5)? ".\n" : "" );
        }
        running ++;

        if(running == 21){
            running = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha

Comment: Just an advice: don't subtract a magic 32 number, it would be clear if you wrote 'a' - 'A'. So, `captLetter=letter - 'a' + 'A'`

Answer (score 5):

Oh, no no no - SegFault:

You create a pointer to a *String Literal* with:

```
    char *captFirstLetter = article[location];
```

You cannot modify the *String Literals* referenced by the pointers in `article`. Your attempt to modify them, e.g.

```
    captFirstLetter[0] = captFirstLetter[0] - 32 ;
```

Invokes *Undefined Behavior* and most probably an immediate SegFault. String literals are stored in read-only memory and cannot be changed (on all but the most ancient and obscure hardware)

To remedy the problem, make sure the strings pointed to by `article` are arrays and not string literals. For example, declare `article` as a 2D array of sufficient size:

```
    char article[][8] = {"the", "a", "one", "some", "any"};
```

Additionally, while you are correctly subtracting `32` to flip the 6th bit (the lower-case bit off), the standard library provides the macro `toupper()` in `<ctype.h>` to handle that case with the proper checks to ensure the case change is limited to lower-case characters. For example:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
    captFirstLetter[0] = toupper(captFirstLetter[0]);
```

Finally, putting it together in a short example explaining the two issues above, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void) {

    char article[][8] = {"the", "a", "one", "some", "any"};
    size_t n = sizeof article / sizeof *article;
    int location = 2;
    char *captFirstLetter = article[location];

    captFirstLetter[0] = toupper(captFirstLetter[0]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        puts (article[i]);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cmplitp2a
the
a
One
some
any
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Might mention how to use `toupper()` while you're at it.

Comment: That's a bit of a more suggestive version of the "no no no" I was thinking about `:)`